# Elinimar Datos de Varias Tablas SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy tratando de eliminar los registros de mi `DB` pero solo se borran las 2 primeras tablas, no ocurre nada en la tercera.

```html
DELETE
  cliente,
  historia,
  descripcion
FROM
  cliente
INNER JOIN
  historia ON historia.idCliente = cliente.idCliente
INNER JOIN
  descripcion ON historia.idDescripcion = descripcion.idDescripcion
WHERE
  cliente.idCliente = 6
```

Solamente se borran la tabla `cliente` e `historia` en la tabla `descripcion` no pasa nada

La `DB` fisica esta relacionado asi;

```
Cliente <----------(1,n) Historia (1,1)-----------> Descripcion
```

Comment: te genera algun error ? ayudanos con el MER de la BD

Comment: El manual especifica que para el borrado no se usa el inner join (va, pero no es la condicion de borrado) si no que la condicion es lo que figura en el where.. si idcliente no esta en la tercer tabla, no va a borrar nada...

Comment: aunque podrias agregar la misma condicion que tenes en el join a la clausula where para las tablas historia y descricpcion, y ver si ahi le gusta y hace el borrado

Comment: No dá ningun error,  quieres decir que solo toma en cuenta el que esta en la clausula `WHERE`?

Comment: eso parece segun el manual.. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html

Comment: Preguntó: ¿a qué se debe que quieras borrar datos así? ¿Qué hay de la integridad referencial, acaso no la estás implementado? Parece que aquí convendría un `ON DELETE CASCADE`, para que no haya registros huérfanos en tus datos.

Comment: el `CASCADE` solo me funciona de un lado, es decir `cliente-historia` o `descripcion-historia`, quedando datos en la otra tabla, ya sea `cliente` o `descripcion`, especificando en la clausula `WHERE` solo elimina **de a 1** y se queda sin registro para seguir con las otras

Answer (score 0):

En lugar de inner, usa left y relaciona las tablas tomando como referencia la primera tabla:

```
DELETE
  cliente,
  historia,
  descripcion
FROM
  cliente
LEFT JOIN
  historia ON cliente.idCliente=historia.idCliente
LEFT JOIN
  descripcion ON descripcion.idDescripcion =historia.idDescripcion
WHERE
  cliente.idCliente = 6
```